# Windows 10 Universal In-App Feedback Mechanism

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Can anyone suggest me some good ways to add In-App Feedback mechanism for users, such as contact information(via email/or website)?
Please answer simple and in easy way, as I am new to development Thanks.

Comment: you can do it two ways 1. Create a form in xaml and submit that to a service from that you write code  to send mail to ur support.2. Create a responsive web page to send mail and load it using webview in xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this reference 
http://aka.ms/store-em-sdk
Check

```
if (Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement.Feedback.IsSupported)
{
 this.feedbackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and then call this method 
`private async void feedbackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
      await Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement.Feedback.LaunchFeedbackAsync();
        }`

Comment: looks like this whole feature is now being deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/feedback-report?source=docs

Comment: sorry bro I left UWP a long time ago